# The grammar of "fueling"

Tags: grammar

> Now at least *five chilling clues* have come to light **fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death**.

[Source](https://www.the-sun.com/news/8970535/clues-prigozhin-still-alive-double/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=sunyoutubestories)

---

Is a "**fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death**" a participal clause as in "**not wanting to hurt his feelings**, I avoided the question."?
Or is it the restrictive relative clause which modifies "*five chilling clauses*"?

Comment: Syntactically, it's ambiguous whether the participial clause starting with ***fueling...*** modifies the noun ***clues*** OR the verb ***come to light*** OR (my preferred parsing)  *the entirety of the preceding text* (as a ***"whole sentence" adverbial***). But *semantically*, this is all nit-picking - I can't see it makes any real difference to the overall meaning which way you look at it.

Comment: Or the non-finite clause could be understood to add information to the entire matrix clause.  *At least five dollars worth of pennies fell from the sky, fueling suspicions that someone in a helicopter may have broken open a piggy bank.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both interpretations are possible.

1. The participial phrase *fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death* may be interpreted as serving the same function as that other phrase in your *not wanting to hurt his feelings* example.  It is clearer with the phrase shifted to the front:

> [Fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death], now at least five chilling clues have come to light.

The participial phrase modifies *five chilling clues have come to light*.

2. The "relative clause" interpretation is also possible.  The original example

> Now at least five chilling clues have come to light fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death.

has undergone **extraposition**; the participial phrase modifying *five chilling clues* has been shifted to the back.  Such a shift is possible as the modifying phrase is long.

The form before extraposition is

> Now at least five chilling clues [fuelling conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death] have come to light.

The participial phrase in the above example has the same meaning as the relative clause before reduction, as shown bracketted below:

> Now at least five chilling clues [**which fuel** conspiracy theories Prigozhin may indeed have dodged death] have come to light.